# Deploying node.js single-page application using AWS Amplify. What are the commands that i should write on the yml file?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, aws-amplify

My project Root Directory is `./backend`.

My build commend is `npm i`.

My start commend is `node server.js`

i dont know how should i tell aws-amplify to do it.

```
version: 1
env:
  variables:
    key: value
backend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - *enter command*
    build:
      commands:
        - *enter command*
    postBuild:
        commands:
        - *enter command*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can learn about all the settings [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/build-settings.html) for your `buildspec.yml` file.

AWS Amplify has a default build commands file in the AWS Console. You can use what they've provided. Otherwise, you're able to customise it in your git project by storing it in the root folder.

I typically run these [commands](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/start/workflows/#uninstall-amplify-cli) in the CLI:

1. `amplify status` - to see the commands
2. `amplify push -y` - to push all the resources

[Here's another useful guide.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/getting-started.html)